# I noticed a local Facebook Group that I am a member of, does not have any admins or moderators

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

As the title says, there are no admins or moderators. Facebook Community says, in this case any member should be able to appoint another member of themselves as an admin. The field should be in the right column but in this case, no such option exists.

Is there something I could do? I tried to find an option to fill out and send a contact form to Facebook but I couldn't find it - everything leads to Community Articles which aren't revealing any additional info.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't have admins or moderators?

Comment: It says so under Administrators and moderators section